# VBA code to get the difference between actual time and updated time

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to check the difference between the time updated in column 'A' and the now function. please assist

`enter code here`8/6/2015  4:06:37 AM - now()

Comment: You can have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227550(v=vs.60).aspx This article shows many different options regarding calculations with times

Answer (score 2):

if you want it in hours

```
 Range("B1").Value = (Now - CDate(Range("A1"))) * 24
```

in minutes

```
 Range("B1").Value = (Now - CDate(Range("A1"))) * 24 * 60
```